# Multinomial Logistic regression, no graphical display using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data obtained from a survey among women. I ran some commands and obtained the coefficients, p value and relative risk as I followed the guidelines displayed by [http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm]
I appreciate them.

I came with the following commands

However, I could not get graphs displayed.

Can someone help me out please?
Thanks.

Here is the data

age:32  39  40  35  55  30  60  55  28  25  35  28  30  50  25  35  47  38  54  38  54  48  52  48  41  51  43  49  51  63  39  64  38  29  36  44  57  28  46  51  22  60  56  55  41  35  30  60  68  30  36  25  45  50  32  43  52  55  45  58  53  51  50  52  80  67  48  38  32  52  35  60  51  34  46  38  35  28  80  48  91  40  45  40  58  40  45  37  38  25  58  53  42  60  70  68  62  53  53  66  40  39  35  32  25  40  40  45  51  48  58  44  47  52  57  35  57  92  88  87  43  44  40  47  41  52  40  42  49  40  37  40  38  30  44  38  39  32  41  38  42  40  29  26  38  31  43  38  36  32  28  28  34  37  32  40  39  31  42  38  38  36

rel:Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Trad    Islam   Trad    Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Islam   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Islam   Chris   Trad    Chris   Chris   Islam   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Islam   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Islam   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Islam   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Trad    Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Trad    Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Trad    Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Trad    Trad    Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris   Chris

pet:Three   Three   Two Three   Three   One Two One Three   One Two Three   Three   Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   One Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Two Two Two Three   Three   Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   One One Three   Three   Three   One Three   Three   One One Three   Three   One One Three   Three   Three   Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   Two One One Two Two One Two One One Two One One One Two One Three   One Two One Two Two Three   One Two Two Two Two Two Two Three   Two Two Two Two Two One One Three   One Three   Three   Three   Three   One Three   Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   One Three   Two One Two Three   Three   Three   Two Two One Three   Two Three   Two Three   Two Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   Two Three   Two Three   Three   Two Two Three   Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Three   Two Three   Three   Three   Three   Three

```
Sec=read.table("Second.txt", header=TRUE)
Sec
attach(Sec)    
library(nnet)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
m1 <- multinom(pet ~ age+rel, data = Sec)
summary(m1)
Relrisk=exp(coef(m1))
Relrisk
z <- summary(m1)$coefficients/summary(m1)$standard.errors
z
p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1))*2
p
 frame=data.frame(age=rep(seq(22,92,by=0.434),3),rel=rep(c("Chris","Islam","Trad"),each=54))
frame
attach(frame)
pred=cbind(frame,predict(m1,newdata=frame,type="probs", se= TRUE))
pred

Preprobmelt=melt(pred,id.vars=c("rel","age"),value.name="Probability")
Preprobmelt

Graph=ggplot(Preprobmelt,aes(x = age,y=Probability, colour=rel,group=age))

geom_line()

facet_grid(variable~ .,scales = "free")

Graph
```

[No lines displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R650d.png)

Comment: Here are a few tips for the [next time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) you want to post a well formed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the necessary plus signs for constructing a ggplot object properly. It should be:

```
 Graph=ggplot(Preprobmelt,aes(x = age,y=Probability, colour=rel,group=age)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(variable~ .,scales = "free")
```

Note carefully how three things are being added together with plus (`+`) signs.

You should probably also explicitly print `ggplot` objects in a script:

```
 print(Graph)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this (you don't need the continuous variable 'age' as group in ggplot aes()):

```
Graph=ggplot(Preprobmelt,aes(x = age,y=Probability, colour=rel)) + 
geom_line(lwd=1.2) +
facet_grid(variable~ .,scales = "free")

Graph
```

[image]